Linux sudo "no puede recuperar la información de autenticación"
Quiero usar sudo su con un root sin contraseña.
Tuve este problema con sudo, me daba ste error.
sudo su
sudo: PAM account management error: El servicio de autenticación no puede recuperar la información de autenticación
sudo: a password is required

Ya intenté con todo esto y no pude resolverlo:
#!/bin/bash

addgroup sudo
usermod -aG sudo root

pam-auth-update --force

chmod 644 /etc/passwd
chmod 400 /etc/shadow
chmod 644 /etc/group
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers

Ya lo había solucionado cambiando cosas en /etc/pan.d.
Y ahora por algún motivo tengo este error:
sudo: PAM account management error: Permiso denegado
sudo: a password is required

Parece que avancé cambiando el binario su original por el de busybox, pero con eso sigue ese error, y cambiando en pam.d también vuelve el error anterior.
¿Qué tendría que hacer para solucionar esto?

Lo solucioné así:

/etc/pam.d/sudo

#%PAM-1.0
auth       required   pam_env.so
account    required   pam_unix.so
password   required   pam_unix.so
session    required   pam_unix.so


Borrando contraseña a root.

passwd -d root

Apareció el error Permiso denegado, no entiendo, pero se solucionó mágicamente, es probable que haciendo algunos ajustes en pam.d cambie algo de la cache del sistema, luego de varios intentos, ya funciona nuevamente.
Si vuelve a ocurrir el problema aviso.
